# get-запрос на редирект

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, requests

Коллеги. Собираю ссылку и делаю гет запрос:

```
url_short = requests.get(domen + 'w/' + short_url + '/')
```

На этой ссылке редирект. Как по нему перейти следом?

Comment: Запросите requests.head() от вашего url-я, там в заголовках наверняка будет редирект в каком-то виде. Ну, если на сайте нормально всё сделано. Проще из заголовков будет достать, чем страницу парсить.

Comment: @ CrazyElf Не, просто отдает "респонс такой-то" и все

Comment: Без конкретики сложно что-то сказать. Редирект может быть сделан разными способами

Answer (score 0):

Вот. я откопал ответ:

```
url_short = requests.get(domen + 'w/' + short_url + '/')
redirect = url_short.url
```

В print(redirect) напечатает ссылку, на которую редирект

Answer (score 0):

Через head запрос (в отличие от get он не получает саму страницу, только http заголовок):

```
h = requests.head('http://ya.ru')
print(h)  # <Response [302]>
print(h.headers['Location'])  # https://ya.ru/
```

Comment: Тоже вариант, спасибо